# How do I make sure these circles always touch - packing problem

Tags: javascript, math, svg

I have 3 circle svgs, which could be of any size.

I want their edges to always touch.

I place a circle, then place another circle next to that circle. Then I place a third circle so it touches both other circles.

I'm so stuck with this - I'm confused about the maths, but I think I'm also not understanding something about svgs

Totally stumped how to make this happen.[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-almeida-x410v)

Comment: Make sure the circles distance apart is the sum of their radii.

Comment: How do you do that in the 2d plane?

Comment: use pythagoras theorem with z being the radius.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have three circles with radii `rᵃ`, `rᵇ` and `rᶜ`. Let's name their center points `A`, `B` and `C`.

You have managed to draw the first two circles by placing `B` at a distance (`rᵃ + rᵇ`) away from `A`, and now you're wondering where to place `C`. Well, `C` needs to be (`rᵃ + rᶜ`) away from `A` and at the same time (`rᵇ + rᶜ`) away from `B`.

Now, how do you find this point `C`? (Hint: Circle-circle intersection)

[image: Circle packing]